# Why would Hash::check always return false?

Tags: php, laravel, hash

In my first controller, I guess, I use the most basic way of creating a user password

**EmployeeController**

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $user = User::create(array(
                'username'  =>  $request->username,
                'password'  =>  Hash::make($tempPassword = Str::random(8)))
        );
        $employee->user()->associate($user);
        $employee->save();
}
```

Shen it comes to checking the password with `Hash::check()` in the second controller it always fails

**ResetPasswordController**

```
public function index(ResetPasswordRequest $request){
        $request->validated();

        $emp = Student::find($request->id);
        if ($emp->user->checkCredentials($request->password)) { //always false

        }
}
```

However, if update password in the same controller (just for testing) it works just fine

**ResetPasswordController**

```
public function index(ResetPasswordRequest $request){
        $request->validated();

        $emp = Student::find($request->id);
        $emp->user->update(['password' =>  Hash::make('abc')]);
        if ($emp->user->checkCredentials('abc')) { //...true

        }
    }
```

**User**

```
public function checkCredentials($password){
        return (Hash::check($password, $this->password)) ? true : false;
    }
```

I don't change the app key between creating and checking the user passwords. Any ideas where else should I look?

Comment: `Hash::check(new_password` should begin with `$`. Is this the real code?

Comment: And what is `$password`? I only see `$old_password`, which is `123`, and you're checking `$old_password` against `$user->password`, but `$old_password` isn't `$password`. Your variables and logic is all over the place....

Comment: Sorry, guys, it was typos in those examples only. I updated to more readable view

Comment: @FelippeDuarte no, it's just a schema of I what I have

Comment: `$user->create()` shouldn't be using `$user`, it should be `User::create()` (a new `User` instance). And make sure you're retrieving the correct user in the 2nd controller. You're creating a User that doesn't seem to have any unique identifier (i.e. email). It might be in your best interest to post the exact code you're using, including how you're creating the user, how you're retrieving the user, how your password is defined (via user input, etc). Your code _should_ work, but with a few assumptions that may or may not be true...

Comment: @TimLewis I updated to my real code

Comment: @FelippeDuarte  I updated to my real code

Comment: So you're assigning a random password via `$tempPassword = Str::random(8)`, it's unlikely that `$request->password` contains the same value as `Str::random(8)`. How are you getting `$request->password`? Is it a `<form>` element? Is the User entering a value? Why aren't you creating the user with a supplied password?

Comment: The user received `$tempPassword` via email and `$request->password` comes from the user when it logged in and what to change password. I receive `$request->password$ as an API request from a mobile client

Comment: The thing is in your code, `$tempPassword` is a `Hash` value, and not a plaintext 8-character string (since you're assigning it to the value of `Hash::make()`). If `$request->password` is that value, it won't work... `$tempPassword` would need to be the plaintext 8-character string to function in `Hash::check()`, but it is likely a Hash, and `Hash::check(Hash::make(...), Hash::make())` (which is essentially what your code boils down to) doesn't work.

Comment: TLDR: do a `dd($tempPassword)`; if it is not an 8 character string, you've got your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206740/discussion-between-virtual-device-and-tim-lewis).

Comment: @TimLewis It would be hash value if I do `$tempPassword = Hash::make(Str::random(8))`, but in case of `Hash::make($tempPassword = Str::random(8)))` $tempPassword is plain text